# Mixer transactions decoding

Tags: transactions, mixing

Did anyone implement the algorithm from this paper [Shared Send Untangling in Bitcoin](http://bitfury.com/content/5-white-papers-research/bitfury_whitepaper_shared_send_untangling_in_bitcoin_8_24_2016.pdf)

I would be interested in seeing it in action.

Comment: The white paper says its writers implemented it themselves and conducted experiments using their implementation.

Comment: Yes, but the implementation was not published.